# Its possible to access a data collection inside of JSON object like this eg. object1.object2.id using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to get the id using a JSON object:

```
"object1":
[
{"name":"Station A","cycleTime":5,"object2":{"id":"60","time":032820200122}}
],
```

this object is running in a json-server on Visual Studio Code

Vue.js Code:

```
<template>

<div>

    <div v-for="object1 in stations" :key="object1">
      
        <h1>{{object1.object2.id}}</h1> 
        
    </div>

</div>


</template>

<script>

export default {
    
    name: 'app',

    data() {
        return {
            stations: [],
            
        }
    },

    mounted() {

        fetch("http://localhost:8000/station")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.station = data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
    },
    

    }

</script>
```

Am trying to get the *id* data from the second object, but when I run the json-server in the console apiary the following error

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Make sure all the variable names are correct in you code snippet

```html
<template>
    <ul id="example-2">
        <li v-for="(item, index) in stations" :key="index">
            <h1>{{item.object2.id}}</h1>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'app',
    data () {
        return {
            stations: [
                {
                    name: 'Station A',
                    cycleTime: 5,
                    object2: {
                        id: '60',
                        time: 032820200122
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        // please make sure after the api call value is assigned to this.stations
        // also the response should have similar structure to the above initial structure
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, its possible do this with the div tag?

Comment: Its works, so in order that the compiler can read the data we need to do indentation. What happen if I try to convert this as a API over the Internet ?

Comment: Yes you can use <div> tag in place of <ul><li>. It doesn't throw any error for that. But it is always a good practice to use <ul><li> with v-for.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in below function: You are using this.station

```
mounted() {

        fetch("http://localhost:8000/station")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.station = data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
    },
```

But your array in data is stations. This is a typo error. Please use this

```
mounted() {

        fetch("http://localhost:8000/station")
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => this.stations = data)
            .catch(err => console.log(err.message))
    },
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the error, thanks for that. Still showing the same error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null.